# log4j in spark main code

Tags: apache-spark, log4j

i want to collect logger according to log4j, i can get the hadoop logger but can't get the main code logger.

tow attached - 1 log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, rolling
log4j.appender.rolling=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.rolling.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.rolling.layout.conversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n
log4j.appender.rolling.maxFileSize=50MB
log4j.appender.rolling.maxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.rolling.file=/home/spark.log
log4j.appender.rolling.encoding=UTF-8
log4j.logger.org.eclipse.jetty=WARN
log4j.logger.org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$exprTyper=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$SparkILoopInterpreter=WARN
log4j.logger.com.test.main.Main=WARN
```

tow attached - 2 com.test.main.Main

```
object Main {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
       val logger = LogManager.getLogger(Main.getClass)
       logger.info("info\n")
       logger.warn("warn\n")
       logger.debug("DEBUG\n")
       logger.error("EEOR\n")
```

now,I can get spark logger in /home/spark.log, such as

> [2018-08-14 18:04:28,852] INFO Running Spark version 2.2.0.cloudera1 (org.apache.spark.SparkContext)
>   [2018-08-14 18:04:29,705] INFO Submitted application: steaming_Test (org.apache.spark.SparkContext)

but no logger in main code such as

> 18:05:17.250 [main] ERROR com.sgm.bgdt.main.Main$ - EEOR

is there a error setting for "**log4j.logger.com.test.main.Main=WARN**"  or something wrong in my **main code**?

PS.

this is my spark submit

```
--driver-java-options "-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/path/log4j.properties
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/path/log4j.properties
```

Comment: do you mean your logger statements are not getting printed to log file?

Comment: You need to supply log4j property file to spark-submit correctly

Comment: thanks your reply. I attached my spark-submit cmd. in that case, some info are collected into specified "/home/spark.log".but infos in application(or log4j.logger.com.test.main.Main) also print in screen.